# How to show size of file from file path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to get all pdf files from device storage and it's done now I want to show the size of that file in listview. builder trailing.

**path of my file**

```
files[index].path
```

**print of files[index].path is**
/storage/emulated/0/android/data/......../name.pdf

**this is what im trying**

```
            title:  Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                  trailing: Text(files[index].path.length()),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list type is `File` you can get that with `length()`:

```
var size = await files[index].length();
print(size);
```

If not try this:

```
var size = await File(files[index].path).length();
print(size);
```

also you can't call it direct in `Text` widget, first you need call it in `FutureBuilder` , second you need to parse its value to string like this:

```
trailing: FutureBuilder<int>(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
  },
  future: files[index].length(),
),
```

Comment: unable to call length function it shows can not find declaration to go to

Comment: what is the type of your list when you hover on it? @FaizanAbbasBangash

Comment: file............

Comment: what do you see  in console when `print("type = ${files.first.runtimeType}");`? @FaizanAbbasBangash

Comment: show _File.....

Comment: can you update your question and show me how are you using it? @FaizanAbbasBangash

Comment: wait let me update

Comment: title only shows name and  i want to show size of that file in trailing

Comment: you are using length on path, check my answer again, and remove the path.

Comment: show this The method 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Text'

Answer (score 1):

use this function as per flutter docs.

```
static String getFileSize(File file) {
int sizeInBytes = file.lengthSync();
double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
double kb = sizeInMb * 1024;
return kb.toStringAsFixed(2);}
```

then you can use this function inside the Text widget like this

'${HomePageUtils.getFileSize(File(widget.file!))} Kbs',

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int sizeInBytes = File(files[index].path).lengthSync();
```